# How can I reordering/sort Interface members with Resharper?

Tags: c#, resharper, code-formatting

I have an existing C# project I've been adding new functionality to, and when I add a new method to my service class(es) I use Resharper to pull the signature of the method up to it's interface. Problem is that after a while the interface has turned into a jumbled mess of methods. I know Resharper can clean/reformat your code and I'd like it to sort the methods in the Interface but I'm not sure how. I've looked at the custom Type Members Layout functionality in Resharpers options but can't seem to get the correct setup to have it take any effect or sorting them.

What XML do I need for the Type Members Layout in Resharper in order to sort the method signatures in an interface?

Answer (score 1):

The best documentation for the XML format I can find is here:

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/01/in-depth-look-at-customizing-type-layout-with-resharper/

If you look at the default XML for the reordering specification, it looks like it probably won't move much code around.

I did change the XML a few versions ago, but I can't remember what I had to change. I *do* remember having to make some changes before it worked though.